# Client calls server countless times as I close and reopen a pop up

Tags: javascript, http, server, request, client

I have a pop up which is opened with Javascript. In this pop up I have a panel that is used for filtering. Every time the user click an option on the Filter and updates the results there is a request sent to the server. However if I close the pop up and reopen it and use the filter again the request will be sent twice and if I keep repeating the same sequence of steps I will continue to increase the requests sent each time by 1.

This is after we open the pop up the first time and filter for first time as you can see there are two request for NarrowEventsSearch
[image: first try]

The image below shows what happens after I close the pop up reopen it again and filter inside of it. We can see that there are now 3 requests sent for NarrowEventsSearch
[image: second try]

This is the js code that opens the pop up 
[image]

the function that is called is the following

```
function tb_show(fake_param, url, callbackFunction) {
SetAjaxCaching(false);
var params = parseThickBoxArgs(url);
trace("----------- Thickbox parameters -----------");
trace("URL Passed was " + url);
trace(params);

var href = params["url"] + "?" + $.param(params);
var dialogTitle = $(this).attr("title");

//Unique id is given for the div
var divId = new Date().getTime().toString();
// Create an anonymous div with a loading gif to be the dialog
var newDiv = $('<div id="' + divId + '"  class="dialogcontainer">' + spinnerHTML + '</div>');

// We push the newly created div onto the window stack so we can keep track of what dialogs are open
window.openedDialogs.push([newDiv, href]);
$('body').append(newDiv);

trace("Opening dialog with height " + params["height"] + " and width " + params["width"]);
//To avoid the scrollbars.
var height = parseInt(params["height"]) + 10;
var width = parseInt(params["width"]) + 10;

if (params["percentWidth"] !== undefined) {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var percentWidth = parseFloat(params["percentWidth"]) / 100.0;

    width = windowWidth * percentWidth;
}
if (params["percentHeight"] !== undefined) {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var percentHeight = parseFloat(params["percentHeight"]) / 100.0;

    height = windowHeight * percentHeight;
}

var CssClass = params["class"];
if (CssClass == undefined) {
    CssClass = '';
}

var title = params["title"];

// Now we actually invoke the dialog function with the parameters we parsed earlier
newDiv.dialog({
    title: title,
    height: height, //params["height"],
    width: width, //params["width"],
    closeOnEscape: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').append("<div style=\"float: right;\"><img src=\"/Resources/Content/Images/Icons/remove.png\" class=\"Delete\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\" onclick=\"closeDialog('" + CssClass + "')\" /></div>");
    }
})
    .load(href, JSON.stringify({ showLoadingBar: false }), function () {
        trace("Overlay Div content loaded");
        // After the content has been loaded, apply the thickbox script to the loaded content
        applyThickboxes($(this));
        // Now run the callback function, if it is indeed a function
        if (typeof (callbackFunction) == 'function') {
            callbackFunction();
        }
    });
hideTitleBar();
//LoadValidation();
```

Comment: Whatever function that is opening the popup is almost certainly binding things like button clicks or dropdown changes every time it runs. We can't tell you what's happening without the code

Comment: should I post the js code ?

Comment: Jesus, @laz , you were literally just told to do so twice.  Also, TKoL is definitely correct - your popup method is definitely rebinding the callbacks to the click handlers every time it opens.  You should bind when you create the popup, and the function that shows the popup should only show it.

Comment: I updated the question . Thanks

Comment: None of that has `NarrowEventsSearch` anywhere...